# How to integrate unity3d AR app inside React native app

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

As I mentioned, I need to insert a unity project into an app in react native.

I saw that there is this component that should help me do this ([react native unity view](https://github.com/f111fei/react-native-unity-view)).

I saw that there is a way to intercept messages sent by unity. (onUnityMessage method), but how do I send some data from react native app to unity? (example: auth token).

I must be able to send the token to unity so that it can be used by unity app.

How can I do this?

thank you in advance!

Comment: did you find any answer?